# How to get specific data from room database when the column is list of strings?

Tags: database, kotlin, android-room

I want to write a query to get data when 'categories' contains "20" .I don't know how. Any help will be appreciated.
This is part of my Entity class :

```
@Entity(tableName = "videos_table")
data class VideosEntity(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        val id: Int = 0,
        var title: String? = "",
        @TypeConverters(com.example.video.database.Converters::class)
        var categories: List<String>? = null
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not to store List<> objects in your database. In your case you should use many-to-many relation instead. Read more https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#many-to-many

Your video categories will be reusable with this approach.